# Angular CdkDragDrop - Identify destination component on drop event

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk-drag-drop

draging from parent componenet to some child componenet (of multiple same type childs)
i am using `(cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"` to point :

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    console.log(event);// how can i get the instance of target component
    }

<app-parent>
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="Data" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"></div>
<app-child cdkDropList></app-child> 
<app-child cdkDropList></app-child> 
<app-child cdkDropList></app-child> 
</app-parent>
```

but i cant obtain from `event` the target component;

Comment: "event" is a  CdkDragDrop, https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDragDrop. So, you has event.container -the container where you dropped the item-, event.previousContainer -the container from your item was dragged-,.... The "containers" are CdkDropList https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDropList, so you has the properties: id,data...

Comment: event.container is an object , i didn't found the target component there..